# Update Old Value to New Value across many Tables using one Master Table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, store

I need to update data that is wrong in many tables in SQL Server using one Master table.

1. Source Table for Update: SRC_TBL_UPD_CST (CST_OLD_ID, CST_NEW_ID)
2. Many tables have a customer id column, such as TBL1 (CST_ID, CST_NM, Salary), TBL2 (CUSTOMERID, Gender, Age) ...
3. I have created a table: LIST_TBL_UPDATE with 2 Columns (Table_name, Customer_ID_column) to store the respective table- and column-names that need updating.

...

```
Table_name |    Customer_ID_column
TBL1       |    CST_ID
TBL2       |    CUSTOMERID
```

.....

I want create a loop to update all tables from SRC_TBL_UPD_CST.CST_OLD_ID to SRC_TBL_UPD_CST.CST_NEW_ID.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you want to do this with SQL, then you're going to need to build an SQL Stored Procedure to generate and execute the SQL statements for you.  If that would be breaking new ground for you, then I'd advocate for a simpler, quicker, lower tech approach using a very straightforward Excel spreadsheet. Just create (copy/paste) a list of all the table names and column names in the first two columns and create a formula to generate the SQL statements you need in the third column as shown in the diagram below. Then copy and paste your SQL statements into the "Run SQL" window of whatever tool you are using and run them. (Note: I'm not using SQL Server these days, so I can't vouch for the accuracy of the UPDATE statement I've shown below, but I'm sure you'll be able to adapt it to your situation). I regularly create SQL Stored Procedures as part of my job, but for one-off, ad-hoc situations like this, I often choose Excel to build the SQL for me. Cheers.

[image]